# Unable to setup route to invoke controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm unable to setup a route to my controller method. I always get the following error in the browser:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8080/TextToSpeech'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'TextToSpeech'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I try to create a simple web service to convert text to speech using ASP.NET self hosting.

Below the controller code:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RESTService.Controller
{
  public class TextToSpeechController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Get")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void Get()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

And the application:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TTS", "{controller}", new { action = "Get" });

using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
  server.OpenAsync().Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Advice on how I can get this to work would be much appreciated.

## Update

I was able to get it to work by specifying the namespace where the controller resides:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TTS", "{controller}/{text}", 
  new[] { "RESTService.Controller" });
```

Comment: Tried `http://localhost:8080/TextToSpeech/Get`?

Comment: Hi @MohsinMehmood, thank you for your reply. No, unfortunately this URL does not work either. With kind regards

Comment: You have your base as ApiController. Try this:
http://localhost:8080/api/TextToSpeech/

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question. That will make this Q&A more accessible for others with the same problem.

Comment: Why do u need this:
HttpSelfHostConfiguration.

Just call it like api/TextToSpeech

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by specifying the namespace where the controller resides:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TTS", "{controller}/{text}", 
  new[] { "RESTService.Controller" });
```